# Show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x+y^2}$ doesn't exist using two-path test

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I show that the limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x+y^2}$$

doesn't exist using two-path test?

All the following paths gave a zero:

- $f(x,0)$
- $f(0,y)$
- $f(x,mx)$
- $f(x,x^2)$
- $f(\sqrt{y},y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want two paths with different outcome, we can easily find that if we take
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x+y^{2}},$$
then 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,0)=0.$$
We now want to find a path where the function is constant $1$, i.e.,
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x+y^{2}}=1\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{y^{2}}{\sqrt{y}-1}$$
We define the path $\gamma:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by
$$\gamma(t)=\left(\frac{t^{2}}{\sqrt{t}-1},t\right).$$
We find
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(\gamma(t))=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Try $x=t^2$ and $y^2=t^2-t^\alpha$ with $t \to 0$ and $\alpha>2$ such that

$$\frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x+y^2}=\frac{t^2\sqrt[4]{t^2-t^\alpha}}{-t^\alpha}=\frac{t^{\frac52}\sqrt[4]{1-t^{\alpha -2}}}{-t^\alpha}=-t^{\left(\frac52-\alpha\right)}\cdot\sqrt[4]{1-t^{\alpha -2}}$$

Comment: This also gives a limit of zero, right?

Comment: try with $\alpha=3$

Comment: or also with $\alpha=\frac52$ (there was a minor typo, I've fixed it)